# Does anyone know if it's possible to fix output to the top of the console after clearing?

Tags: python, console, game-development

I'm working on building a casino application and I want the user's login info (username & balance) to be fixed to the console even after clearing it. I have to clear the console because then there's going to be a bunch of inputs and prints that I don't want to be visible anymore. Not sure if the only way is to just clear the console and it reprint the information I want or if there is alternative ways. Below I've included an example of something I would like. Thank you!

Code:

```
balance = 100
user = 'username'   
print(f"Balance: {balance} User: {user}") # I want to keep this output constantly visible, even after clearing my console
# dummy output I want to eventually clear
for i in range(200):
    print('hi')
clearConsole()
```

Console:

> Balance: 100
> User: username

Answer (score 0):

the code you'd need for that is this:

```
import os

balance = 100
user = 'username'   
print(f"Balance: {balance} User: {user}")
"""
for i in range(200):
    print('hi')     not sure if you need this
"""

os.system('cls')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go!
Use subprocess.

**Assuming that you are using MacOS,**

```
import subprocess

def clearConsole():
    subprocess.call("clear",shell=True)

balance = 100
user = 'username'
print(f"Balance: {balance} User: {user}")
for i in range(200):
    print('hi')
clearConsole()
print('this is a new line')
```

If you are using Windows, change the call function to

```
subprocess.call("cls",shell=True)
```